# Shell Script: Truncating String

Tags: string, shell

I have two folders full of trainings and corresponding testfiles and I'd like to run the fitting pairs against each other using a shell script.

This is what I have so far:

```
for x in SpanishLS.train/*.train
do
    timbl -f $x -t SpanishLS.test/$x.test
done
```

This is supposed to take `file1(-n).train` in one directory, look for `file1(-n).test` in the other, and run them trough a tool called `timbl`.
What it does instead is look for a file called `SpanishLS.train/file1(-n).train.test` which of course doesn't exist.
What I tried to do, to no avail, is truncate `$x` in a way that lets the script find the correct file, but whenever I do this, `$x` is truncated way too early, resulting in the script not even finding the `.train` file.

How should I code this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `basename`:

```
for x in SpanishLS.train/*.train
do
    timbl -f $x -t SpanishLS.test/$(basename "$x" .train).test
done
```

That removes the directory prefix and the `.train` suffix from `$x`, and builds up the name you want.

In `bash` (and other [POSIX-compliant shells](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)), you can do the `basename` operation with two shell [parameter expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) without invoking an external program.  (I don't think there's a way to combine the two expansions into one.)

```
for x in SpanishLS.train/*.train
do
    y=${x##*/}                                        # Remove path prefix
    timbl -f $x -t SpanishLS.test/${y%.train}.test    # Remove .train suffix
done
```

Beware: `bash` supports quite a number of (useful) expansions that are not defined by POSIX.  For example, `${y//.train/.test}` is a `bash`-only notation (or `bash` and compatible shells notation).

Comment: The substitutions are not Bash only, but POSIX sh, aren't they?

Comment: @tripleee Hmmm...yes, the `##` and `%` (and `#` and `%%`) expansions are in [POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).  Another comment elsewhere suggests `${x//.train/.test}`; that is not a POSIX expansion.  I've updated my answer—thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks! That was way more elegant than I imagined!

Answer (score 4):

If I got you right, this will do the job:

```
for x in SpanishLS.train/*.train
do
    y=${x##*/}  # strip basepath
    y=${y%.*} # strip extention
    timbl -f $x -t SpanishLS.test/$y.test
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all occurences of `.train` in the filename to `.text`:

```
timbl -f $x -t $(echo $x | sed 's/\.train/.text/g')
```

Comment: can do this just in bash: `-t ${x//.train/.test}`

Comment: This does not deal with the `SpanishLS.train` vs `SpanishLS.test` path prefixes.